# Ansible shutdown and startup of Oracle DB on Debian host

Tags: database, oracle, ansible, debian

A DB administrator has given me the following commands to stop and then start an Oracle DB running on Debian(10):

stop db:

```
sudo su - <DBadminName>
lsnrctl status
lsnrctl stop
sqlplus / as sysdba
shut immediate;
```

start db:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
startup;
lsnrctl start
```

We manage all of the servers in this infrastructure with Ansible, but we have thus far not done any direct interactions with the Oracle db , with Ansible.

We are being asked for additional automation and this stop/start is currently being done manually.

Can this db stop/start process be automated with Ansible?

Answer (score 0):

You will find real world code examples on Github. Make sure you have an account.

```
# github code search function - 'ghc' 
declare -f ghc
ghc ()
{
    args=("$@");
    SEARCH_STRING_PLUSSIGN=$(printf '%s' "${args[@]/%/+}");
    open "$(echo "https://github.com/search?q=${SEARCH_STRING_PLUSSIGN%?}&type=code")"
}

# fire and code will be nicely highlighted in your browser
ghc ansible oracle shutdown immediate
```

Best of luck!